# Centering a list while maintaining no indentation

Tags: html, css, list

Okay, I have a list, and I want to center everything in it using CSS.

Anyway, I googled it, and I found, to remove the list style, and no left margin. But, I want to center it also, so I use `text-align:center;`. But for some reason, the indent shows up, so it is not exactly in the center, which is what I want.

If you want a example, there's one at [tst.burngames.net](http://tst.burngames.net)

Since everyone apparently needs code when there's a website..

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div id="search">
        <input id="search_input" placeholder="Search for game.">
        <ul id="search_list">
            <li>
                One
            </li>
            <li>
                Two
            </li>
            <li>
                Three
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {

    background: url(../images/fire.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#search {

    background-color:white;
    border-color:black;
    border-style:double;
    border-width: thick;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-bottom:auto;
    width:600px;
    height:100%;
}

#search_input {

    width:99%;
    height:50px;
    margin-top:20px;
    text-align:center;
}

#search_list {

    width: 99%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;

}
li {

    list-style-type:none;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    text-align:center;

}
```

Comment: Do you want to center it relative to the list, page, or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example should help:

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="nice">
    <li>James</li>
    <li>Dan</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.nice {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Here is a working jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/8NjfW/1/.

## Update

Here is a working jsFiddle in regard to your new code - http://jsfiddle.net/APv9P/

Comment: Look at the code I just added, for some reason that doesn't work.

Comment: Eh, you had the closest to what happened, the thing had width 99% for the ul, and somehow it indents it a bit more to the right..

Comment: Yeah check this - http://jsfiddle.net/APv9P/ - I just added padding:0px to the UL.

Answer (score 0):

Try throwing it in to a DIV and centering the DIV.

Answer (score 0):

The indent shows up because of the default formatting of documents by the user [agent style sheet](http://meiert.com/en/blog/20070922/user-agent-style-sheets/). To get rid off of the padding, just add `padding: 0` to your `#search_list`.

```
#search_list {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 99%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```